# How to save/retrieve image and text in severless java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I am building a serverless java application where I want to give facility to my customer to enter there Bank account details and upload last three month back statement in PDF, PNG, JPEG format, and also I need to be able to retrieve the info for verification. I am using Serverless , Lambda, JAVA dynamodb as my tech stack. Please help me or suggest me to build this feature.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using S3 presigned URLs. In your serverless code you use the S3 SDK to create the presigned URL. You pass the URL back to the client from your Lambda. The client then has a certain amount of time to use the URL to upload the image.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: Can you please share an example for this in java? I am not able to figure how to do it?